# Subset with symbol &

Tags: r, subset

Good evening, 
I have a strange problem. 
I have "airports" data, data include variable "type" - small airport, large, heliports, etc.
I'm trying to subset (in new object) ONLY large airports and baloonports.

code look like:

```
airportsBIG <- subset(airportsUS, type == "large_airport" & type =="balloonport")
```

I check it separately:

```
airportsBIG <- subset(airportsUS, type == "large_airport")
```

and it's work. Doesn't work when I'm trying put them together in a line with "&" symbol. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `&` didn't work is because they are not in the same row but in different rows.  The `&` checks whether both the values are present in the same row or not.  In this case, we need a `%in%`

```
subset(airportsUS, type %in% c("large_airport", "balloonport"))
```

However, if we are checking for possible substrings,

```
subset(airportsUS, grepl("large_airport",  type) & grepl("balloonport", type))
```

Or

```
subset(airportsUS, 
    grepl("\\blarge_airport\\b.*\\bballoonport|\\bballoonport\\b.*\\blarge_airport\\b",
                  type))
```